Error en posgresql con la extension de mysql_fwd al extraer datos de un host externo atravez del proxysql (Failed to store the result)
Error: failed to store the result
Estoy usando Proxy SQL para balancear las cargas entre un grupo de nodos de mariadb (1 nodo para escritura y uno para las lecturas). Tengo clientes en nodejs y php que se conectan correctamente.
Pero tengo un cliente mas que es una base de datos en PostgreSQL que necesito conectar a my proxysql para que acceda a los datos de mis nodos de mariadb. Para conectarme a mi proxysql estoy usando mysql_fwd.
Versiones:

ProxySQL versión 2.6.3-107-gcdfcfdc
Mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.18-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu
(x86_64) using EditLine wrapper
PostgreSQL 13.10 (Ubuntu 13.10-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit

Lo que esta sucediendo es que en PostgreSQL al seleccionar mi tabla foránea me encuentro con el error "failed to store the result" que únicamente se presenta cuando en el select incluyo el campo tipo text ( select address from db.tabla ) conectandome al proxysql y este error no se presenta si me conecto directamente a los nodos de mysql.
Actualmente encontré una solución que no me es factible aplicar que implica cambiar el tipo de dato de mi campo tipo text a "character varyin" al crear mi tabla foránea en PostgreSQL (Me resulta extraño que esto funcione ya que el campo es tipo text desde el origen).
No me es factible ya que actualmente tengo muchas vistas en posgresql ya asociadas y se presenta un error al cambiar los tipos de datos.
Definición de mi tabla en mariadb:
Field, Type, Collation, Null, Key, Extra, Privileges
'id', 'int(11)', NULL, 'NO', 'PRI', 'auto_increment', 'select,insert,update,references'
'fiscal_address', 'text', 'utf8mb3_general_ci', 'YES', '', '', 'select,insert,update,references'

Como me conecto desde posgresql con la extension de mysql_fwd a mi proxysql:
CREATE SERVER mysql_svr
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql_fdw
OPTIONS (
  host '178.1.1.1' , init_command 'SET SESSION wait_timeout=120', port '6033', reconnect 'true'
);

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER mysql_svr
OPTIONS (username 'userremote', password 'password');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE db.tabla(
  id int,
  address text
)
SERVER mysql_svr OPTIONS (dbname 'db', table_name 'tabla');

select id from db.tabla; // Se ejecuta correctamente
select address  from db.tabla;  // Se presenta el error failed to store the result

Configuración del Proxy SQL
mysql_variables = {
 default_query_timeout=36000000
 poll_timeout=5000
 server_version="5.5.30"
 default_collation_connection="utf8_general_ci"
 default_charset="utf8"
}                                                                             

mysql_servers = ( 
  { address="178.1.1.11" , port=3306 , hostgroup=1 }, -- escritor
  { address="178.1.1.12" , port=3306 , hostgroup=2 , max_replication_lag = 60 } -- lector
)

mysql_users: (
 { username = "userremote" , password = "password" , default_hostgroup=1 , active = 1 }
)

mysql_query_rules:(
        {
                rule_id=1
                active=1
                match_digest="^SELECT .*"
                destination_hostgroup=2
                apply=1
        },
        {
                rule_id=2
                active=1
                match_pattern=".*"
                destination_hostgroup=1
                apply=1
        }
)

